# Does Crash ever visit the other 12 planets in his star system?

Tags: crash-bandicoot-2

In Crash Bandicoot 2, we learn that Crash and Co. exist in another solar system from this quote by Dr. Neo Cortex.

> There are crystals to be gathered, 30 to be precise.  The planets will align shortly, **all 13 of them**.

This means that besides the planet they are on, there's a dozen other planets in the Crash Bandicoot universe.

Does Crash, or anyone else, ever visit those dozen planets in the series?  Or is this fact drop forgotten entirely?

Comment: have you visited all the planets in our universe?

Comment: @Dupree3 No, but I've also never worn a Tiki mask or travelled through time.

Comment: This is a fair point....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Crash Bandicoot (all of them as far as I know), Crash is on Earth. In Crash Bandicoot, he is on an archipel near Australia, in Cortex Strikes Back (Crash Bandicoot 2) he travels using the "warp room" to collect cristals on Earth and in Warped (Crash Bandicoot 3) he travels in time but still on planet Earth. Of course the Earth of Crash Bandicoot is different from ours as the solar system. I hope this answers your question !

Comment: Not really, since there have been far more games in the series, but thank you for the effort anyway.

Comment: I checked Wikipedia and there is no game in which Crash goes to another planet. In Crash 2, the alignement of the planets produces a kind of energy which is collectible by the "Cortex-Vortex" using the crystals. To me, the other planets are used here to make "plausible" the story, they were not intended to be visited.

Comment: Now that "Crash Bandicoot 4: It's About Time" is out, Crash does visit another planet in the level "Crash Landed".

Answer (score -3):

Cortex knows Crash is pretty stupid, so he lied to him to convince him to continue gathering crystals. While video games technically all take place in alternate universes, it’s still the Solar System and therefore there are only nine planets (when the game was first made; Pluto is now considered a dwarf planet).

tl;dr Thirteen planets is a lie by Cortex, as always.